# Angular flex-layout not wrapping correctly

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

We have an Angular site and on the dashboard there are multiple sections.  On a full screen they show in 2 columns.  The right column correctly shows with no gabs, but the left column has gaps when boxes in the right are to large.  I've attached a plunkr that shows the gaps.  I've tried multiple configurations but can't seem to get the left column to work the same as the right.  Make sure to widen the preview enough that there are 2 columns.

[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DFGju7uMoBEWzpoKGhMf?p=preview)

template.html

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Main page wrapper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
            <!-- Main view/routes wrapper-->
            <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="content" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
                        <div fxFlexOrder="0">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 sec1">
                                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                                    <div class="ibox-title">
                                        <h5>Box 1 Title</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-content text-center">
                                        <h2>Box 1 content</h2>
                                        <h2>Box 1 content</h2>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-footer text-center">
                                        <h4>box footer </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div fxFlexOrder="1">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 sec2">
                                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                                    <div class="ibox-title">
                                        <h5>Box 2 Title</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-content text-center">
                                        <h2>Box 2 content</h2>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-footer text-center">
                                        <h4>box footer </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div fxFlexOrder="2">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 sec3">
                                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                                    <div class="ibox-title">
                                        <h5>Box 3 Title</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-content text-center">
                                        <h2>Box 3 content</h2>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-footer text-center">
                                        <h4>box footer </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div fxFlexOrder="3">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 sec4">
                                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                                    <div class="ibox-title">
                                        <h5>Box 4 Title</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-content text-center">
                                        <h2>Box 4 content</h2>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-footer text-center">
                                        <h4>box footer </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>




                        <div fxFlexOrder="5">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 no-padding sec5">
                                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                                    <div class="ibox-title">
                                        <h5>Box 5 Title</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-content text-center">
                                        <h2>Box 5 content</h2>
                                        <h2>Box 5 content</h2>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-footer text-center">
                                        <h4>box footer </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div fxFlexOrder="6">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 sec6">
                                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                                    <div class="ibox-title">
                                        <h5>Box 6 Title</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-content text-center">
                                        <h2>Box 6 content</h2>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-footer text-center">
                                        <h4>box footer </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End wrapper-->
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

css

```
.sec1 {
  background: red;
  color:white;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.sec2 {
  background: yellow;
  color:blue;

}

.sec3 {
  background: blue;
  color:white;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.sec4 {
  background: green;
  color:white;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.sec5 {
  background: purple;
  color:white;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.sec6 {
  background: orange;
  color:white;
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your goal is to make it so the content on the left does NOT have any gaps?

Comment: Yes, I'd like there to be no gaps. because some of the boxes can have a lot of content which causes big gaps.